# Reorganise array, move indexes to specific locations php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I have an arbitrary number of arrays all containing the same format of data. There are 2 separate for loops looping through two separate SQL query results and adding them to 2 separate arrays.

Once I have all the information in both arrays, I am walking through them and joining them together to make a longer array.

However, as I am writing this array to a csv file, The information needs to be in order in the array so it writes it in order to the csv file. How can I do this?

**Array 1**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-21 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 32.63
            [4] => 18.36
            [5] => 98.46
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-21 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 29.74
            [4] => 148.68
            [5] => 178.42
        )

     //etc
```

**Array 2**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => RTGH707321222
            [1] => THIS
            [2] => IS
            [3] => TEXT
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => RTGH707321220
            [1] => SOME
            [2] => WORDS
            [3] => HERE
        )

    //etc
```

**Joining the arrays together**

```
array_walk($array2, function($values, $key) use (&$array1) {

        $array1[$key] = array_merge($array1[$key], $values);
    } );
```

**After The array Merge - print_r($array1)**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-21 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 32.63
            [4] => 18.36
            [5] => 98.46
            [6] => RTGH707321222
            [7] => THIS
            [8] => IS
            [9] => TEXT
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-21 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 29.74
            [4] => 148.68
            [5] => 178.42
            [6] => RTGH707321220
            [7] => SOME
            [8] => WORDS
            [9] => HERE
        )

     //etc
```

So this is working fine. However, I would like to move some of these indexes around so that they are in a different order. I have looked into array_splice() but I am not sure if this is the correct method to use.

**What I want it to look like**

```
[1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2017-07-21 00:00:00
                [1] => RTGH707321222
                [2] => TEXT
                [3] => THIS
                [4] => 18.36
                [5] => 98.46
                [6] => Foo
                [7] => 32.63
                [8] => IS
                [9] => Bar
            )

        //etc
```

As you can see, all the information is still the same. The values have just been moved to different indexes. How can I sort the array so that it looks like the above. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic you are applying to change your indices

Comment: I have not changed anything yet. Thats why I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simpler method using `array_replace()` and an ordering array.

No extra loop, no temporary swapping variables.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d0347acba8f13204cc2208237090729547ea723))

```
$array1=[
    1=>['2017-07-21 00:00:00','Foo','Bar',32.63,18.36,98.46],
    2=>['2017-07-21 00:00:00','Foo','Bar',29.74,148.68,178.42]
];
$array2=[
    1=>['RTGH707321222','THIS','IS','TEXT'],
    2=>['RTGH707321220','SOME','WORDS','HERE']
];
$order=[0=>'',6=>'',9=>'',7=>'',4=>'',5=>'',1=>'',3=>'',8=>'',2=>''];
array_walk($array2, function($values, $key) use (&$array1,$order) {
    $array1[$key] = array_replace($order,array_merge($array1[$key], $values));
});
var_export($array1);
```

Comment: It says unexpected [ on line 170 $order=[0=>'',6=>'',9=>'',7=>'',4=>'',5=>'',1=>'',3=>'',8=>'',2=>''];

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji Are you using PHP >= 5.4 ?  If not just replace with `$order=array(0=>'',6=>'',9=>'',7=>'',4=>'',5=>'',1=>'',3=>'',8=>'‌​',2=>'');`

Comment: yeah i just realised haha. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

we can use swap technice here like,

```
<?php
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $swap = $value[1];
        $arr[$key][1] = $value[6];
        $arr[$key][6] = $swap;
        $swap = $value[9];
        $arr[$key][9] = $value[2];
        $arr[$key][2] = $swap;
        $swap = $value[7];
        $arr[$key][7] = $value[3];
        $arr[$key][3] = $swap;
    }
    print_r($arr);
?>
```

`$arr` is your array.